# "_fbBatchedBridge is undefined" error while trying to integrate a react-native app with an existing ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

Doing a react-native integration into an existing ios app.
I have a native ios app which pulls in the ios bundle from a remote server.
I followed the instructions on the react-native site (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html) and i am able to install pod dependencies within React and startup the ios app in a simulator.

When i navigate to the view that loads the react-native provided view, the code for loading the react-native app in that view looks something like

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://<some_url_here>/main.jsbundle"; //a remotely hosted bundle.
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                             moduleName: @"react-native-app"
                                             initialProperties: nil
                                                 launchOptions:nil];
```

when i directly hit the `https://<some_url_here>/main.jsbundle` i do see the bundle get downloded, so i do know that that url does serve the bundle.

The problem i am seeing is when i try to load the view, i see a red screen with:

```
_fbBatchedBridge is undefined
```

When i searched on the web for this issue, seems like the issue happens when app tries to pull the bundle from dev-server but the dev-server is not running. That does not apply to my case as the bundle is hosted remotely.

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Is this on a device or a simulator? That error could mean the app can't reach the local devserver running on port 8081. Using a simulator is easier.

Comment: I am using a simulator. But i am trying to load the bundle from a remote server , not from a localhost. 
1. Generated a bundle from my project,
2. Hosted that bundle on a remote server
3. Pulling that bundle from the remote server into my ios app.

Comment: Here is some more info from the stack trace on xcode:
line: 5537\n message: undefined is not an object (evaluating \'Object.keys(moduleConfig.methods)\')', { [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(moduleConfig.methods)')]
  line: 5537,
  column: 28,
  sourceURL: 'http://<myserver>/ios/mainjsbundle' }

Answer (score -1):

This might be an ATS (App Transport Security) related issue.  Try disabling it for the domain you're connecting to just for debugging.

In your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.the-domain-name.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Xamarin has a [nice explanation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/) for refining the ATS settings.

Comment: Sure. i did already have the following in .plist as an allow all for the time being. But once i got it working, i was planning on narrowing the domain further down.
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>

But it does not seem to help :(